# Query to flip the Alphabets' case

Tags: sql, oracle

write a  query to accept 4 characters example -aBcD  and convert it from upper to lower case format and lower to upper case i.e AbCd format you can use ASCII character function but you must not use any PL/SQL code and it should be only a SQL Query

Comment: create function like mixedcase, and do it in pl sql, reusable it is..

Comment: I need a cup of coffee and a muffin, thanks. (Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: in Pl/SQL we can do it but i need it in SQL  query form only they have given me a hint also we can use ASCII function here

Comment: please add to your question that you can use ascii function and not pl/sql

Comment: Is this a homework assignment question?

Comment: no this is the question asked to me in the interview

Comment: Why not just `translate('aBcD','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')`

Answer (score 2):

```
   with letters as
    (
    select 
           substr('MaHeSh',level,1) as letter,level row_label
    FROM dual
    connect by level<= length('MaHeSh')
    )
    select 
           listagg(
           case when ascii(letter) between ascii('a') and ascii('z') then
           upper(letter)
           else
           lower(letter)
           end,'') within group ( order by row_label) as flipped
    from
    letters
```

**Result**:

```
FLIPPED

mAhEsH
```

**Working**

We split the word into letters and convert them as rows using substr() function

`SUBSTR('Mahesh',2,1) = 'a'` extracts the 2nd letter. using connect by, we generate virtual rows equal to length of the word, and extract letter by letter like below. Later do a ascii check and flip case accordingly. LISTAGG will group all the letters again into one word.

The view generated(row label is to preserve the order of letters)

```
LETTER  ROW_LABEL
M   1
a   2
H   3
e   4
S   5
h   6
```

Comment: How this will work can you explain me

Comment: tried as much as i can to explain in my answer.!

Comment: I know people who have written sql/plsql for more than 10 years and could not have solved that for a variable number of characters.  good answer...